# Custom auth keyclock with Java

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to create a .JAR file to include it in the keylock settings.

My keycloack is tied to LDAP, but I have external company users who control access to a table in Oracle and not LDAP.

From what I read in the documentation, I need to create a JAR to do this. But I could not.

My code:

```
package br.com.auroracoop;

import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.CreatedResponseUtil;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.CredentialRepresentation;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String username = "my-user";
        String password = "my-password";

        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("https://myserver.com.br")
                .realm("REALM")
                .clientId("CLIENT")
                .clientSecret("SECRET")
                .username("ADMIN")
                .password("ADMIN")
                .build();

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/my_database", "root", "password");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'");

        if (resultSet.next()) {

            UserRepresentation tempUser = new UserRepresentation();
            tempUser.setUsername(username);
            tempUser.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            tempUser.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            tempUser.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
            tempUser.setEnabled(true);

            Response response = keycloak.realm("aurora").users().create(tempUser);
            keycloak.close();

            CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
            credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
            credential.setValue(password);
            credential.setTemporary(true);

            tempUser.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credential));

            String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);

            Keycloak keycloak2 = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("https://myserver.com.br")
                .realm("REALM")
                .clientId("CLIENT")
                .clientSecret("SECRET")
                .username("ADMIN")
                .password("ADMIN")
                .build();

            AccessTokenResponse token = keycloak2.tokenManager().getAccessToken();

            keycloak2.close();

        } else {
            System.out.println("User does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is as follows, get to the keycloack and check if the user exists, if it doesn't exist in the keycloack check the database to see if it exists.

If it exists in the bank, I need to create the user in the keycloack, authenticate it and return the user's token to other applications that use SSO to authorize the user.

Does this code of mine make sense?